# iPhone Could Not Support Development

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, provisioning, organizer

I recently reinstalled OSX. It has been a pain rounding up all of my certificates, etc, but I finally am back. However, when trying to install an app on either of two iPhones 3G's I have, they both say:

Software version: 4.2.1 (8C148) | XCode cannot find the software image to install this version. | Could not support development.

What is going on? Both iPhones list themselves as up to date in iTunes, and iOS developer's center only lists 4.2 as the available SDK.

EDIT: I do have a paid membership, and I have recently had test apps installed on both of these devices.

UPDATE: I removed all 3 ( the 2 included ) of my devices from the provisioning portal, and deleted them from the organizer, closed XCode, detached device, restarted, plugged in device, no luck.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Classic ;-)

1. connect the iphone
2. Go to Xcode -> Window -> organizer
3. find your iphone and press "Use for development"
4. As Jacob said: try adding / removing your device as well

**If you still get this error you have an out of date XCode**

Comment: I'm in the organizer, that is where these errors are popping up. I had initially done that before the reinstall, but the option isn't there.

Comment: I just checked the info, holy crap my XCode is version 3.2.5! I must not have updated after the reinstall T_T

Comment: Oh wait, that is the new one, isn't it :p How do I tell if my iOS SDK is the most recent version?

Comment: Well, I again have no clue, I tried a quick scratch app and it installed perfectly. I'll just have to mess with it some more.

Comment: Pulling out my hair on this one... Upgraded to OS X Lion, updated XCode, but until I removed/re-added my device (as @Jacob said), it was no go.

Comment: Steps 1-3 worked for me. Using new iPhone 4S iOS 5.1.1 with Xcode 4.3.3 on Mac OS X 10.7.4. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Unfortunately this appears even though I'm on newest Xcode and iPad is not on a beta release. *hums*

Comment: Re-inserted cord. Latest version of XCode as of 2012-10-09.

Answer (score 115):

I just got this error with Xcode 4.0.2 and an iPhone 3G running 4.2.1 (the final 4.x allowed on a 3G). I restarted Xcode and it went through the process of collecting debug information, then gave me a green light. Other answers here say that you may also need to quit iTunes for this to work.

Conclusion: **Try restarting Xcode**. Quit iTunes first if it was open.

Comment: @neven Just had this issue and restarted. Good thing I checked before just reinstalling everything. Thanks.

Comment: Haha, you're welcome. Glad to have saved you an hour of looking at a progress bar!

Comment: A simple restart made it for me too.

Comment: Restarting my MacBook Pro worked for me.  (Restarting XCode or "properly" turning off my iPod wasn't sufficient.)

Comment: Restarted Xcode, iTunes and iPhone a number of times to no avail. Restarting Mac worked.

Comment: I had the same issue and your answer gave it away for me. In my case it wasn't itunes that was opened but another version of Xcode (I was testing Xcode 5 DP 5 as well as having my Xcode4.6.3 opened).

Comment: Had to restart twice :P

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem with IOS 5.0.1 and Xcode 4.2.  I restarted Xcode as other suggested.  However, I also needed to close iTunes which had started automatically and eject my iPhone from iTunes.  Then, restart Xcode and it worked fine.

Comment: Worked for me by just quitting iTunes & re-plug the phone (3GS with 5.0.1)

Comment: worked for me as well. Apparently iTunes is causing this in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just encountered this problem.  First, I had both an expired certificate and expired provisioning profile, so had to fix both (and I do this so rarely that it took a good 45 minutes).  Then still got the error.  Tried phone off/on -- no joy.  Shut down Organizer and restarted -- no luck there either.  Killed Xcode and restarted, with no luck.

Finally, I turned off the phone, shut down the Mac, turned off the overhead lights, and spun around three times clockwise in my swivel chair, then started everything up again.  Then it worked.

(I suspect that iTunes was active and had something to do with the problem.)

Comment: Funny, that is how I do most of my iOS development.

Answer (score 3):

[This one worked](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1664/_index.html) for me just now (power cycle the iOS device)

Answer (score 1):

I just had this happen as well.  None of the above solutions seemed to work.  In the end, it turned out to be a faulty iPhone charge cable.  So check that too if you see this message!

Comment: in my case, faulty usb slot on my laptop

Answer (score 0):

Try **freeing up memory by closing down unnecessary open apps**. I tried restarting XCode and shutting down iTunes but still had the problem. Then I noticed I was running low on memory on my 4GB MacBook White. I closed down all non-essential apps and when I was done the green light had lit up beside my iPad3 and I could run my app on it.

For me the combination of Google Chrome with lots of tabs open and XCode often is enough to use up all my available RAM; where 4 Gigs used to be plenty of memory for iOS development, with XCode 4.2 it's feeling a bit cramped.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when I changed the name of my phone from "mark X's phone" to a more anonymous name. Removed profile, reconnected phone, worked automatically from there.

Comment: This would be better as a comment than it is as an answer.  Hopefully, it will be helpful to someone, though.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.

In my case I had to

1. open itunes and agree to a new software agreement.
2. I first agreed to it on the developer portal and then from within
           itunes.
3. I closed itunes, restarted xcode and my Ipad was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 5, iPhone 4S, no new name or any other changes that I can think of.

I simply quit iTunes, disconnected the cable, reconnected the cable. Then the organiser gave me the green light.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused by a lack of free storage space on the device - after deleting a few videos and app documents, Xcode organiser was able to complete the "symbol copying" etc process. It doesn't appear to need much space for this, so if iTunes doesn't show the storage as being nearly full it's almost certainly not the cause for other people.