# "Could not support development" iPad 5.1 + Xcode 4.3

Tags: ipad, xcode4.3, ios5.1

I am using Xcode 4.3 and when my iPad with iOS5.1 is connected, organizer do recognize my iPad but saying

"**Could not support development**".

I tried another iPad with same iOS without any problem.

Anyone has any clue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652590/iphone-could-not-support-development

that worked for me

Comment: After upgrade the iOS to 5.1.1, problem solved.

Answer (score 13):

Power off the device and then power it on again.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1664/_index.html

Comment: I saw this with XCode 4.5 and iOS 5.1.1 on an iPad 1.  Restarting the iPad worked for me. [tag:xcode4.5]

Answer (score 10):

Powering on/off didn't work for me.  However, I think there was some dirt or something in the 30-pin connector.  I blew on it to clean it out, and voila, it worked.

Bonus:  If you know what a Nintendo cartridge is, this trick will take you down memory lane.