# Upgrade ios deployment target from 5.1 to 5.1.1 in xcode 4.3.2

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3

How can i upgrade my ios deployment target version from 5.1 to 5.1.1. I have install 5.1.1 on my iPad but in xcode deployment target I can not get the newest version from the drop down list in both of(Project->info->Deployment Target->ios Development target and Target->Summary->ios Application Target->Deployment Target). But in this drop down I am not getting the latest ios version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to deploy only to 5.1.1?

Comment: My app needs to upgrade on this version according to the client requirement

Comment: Xcode 4.3 doesn't know there is an iOS 5.1.1, so you cannot do this.  (Xcode 4.4 doesn't know either - yet).

Comment: So according to you if i upgrade my xcode version it will automatically upgrade ios deployment target, otherwise manually up gradation is impossible.

Comment: Not necessarily, but the tools need to know what versions of iOS are available in order to support them (or at least the SDKs do).

Comment: i have xcode 4.3.2, os 10.7.3, ios 5.1. So can i upgrade it.

Comment: Xcode 4.3.2 is the latest released version. You can upgrade to Xcode 4.4 if you are a registered Mac developer but you cannot 'release' code using it until it has been officially released itself.

Comment: No I dont want to upgrade my xcode version, i just want to say that can i upgrade my  ios deployment target version from 5.1 to 5.1.1 in my xcode 4.3.2.

Comment: Unable to read symbols for /Users/abc/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.1.1 (9B206)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader (file not found).
warning: No copy of AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session. Actually due to not upgrading my version i get this worning when i am running my project on iPad

Comment: same problem here i need to deploy on 5.1.1 my clients are working on this version as my iPad too so can't test on my device

Comment: If you get any solution then please let me know the procedure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652590/iphone-could-not-support-development

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today, when I tried to symbolicate crash reports from phones that were on 5.1.1.  The addresses would not symbolicate because symbolicatecrash.pl could not find the symbols for 5.1.1.  The solution from Apple is here: basically plug in a phone with 5.1.1 and Xcode will load the symbols.

https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3461/diff?secondVersionNumber=8

Comment: How do you know if Xcode is downloading the symbols for iOS 5.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am late but here is what was issue with me. My xCode was debugging fine for iOS 5.1.1 (9B206) however, my other iPhone was running iOS 5.1.1 (9B208) and thus the above problem as you face.

The solution was to copy the debug symbols from the working version to the non-working one. Here is how

- Enable Showing Hidden files
- Navigate to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.1.1 (9B206)/Symbols/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld`
- Copy the available three files
- Navigate to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.1.1 (9B208)/Symbols/System/Library/Caches/com.apple.dyld`
- Paste the files.
- Detach the device and attach again.

Worked perfectly for me .. =)