# Can't download App to iOS 5.1.1 iPhone

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3, ios5, ios5.1

I installed the latest iOS update (5.1.1) on my development iPhone.  In Xcode, I now get the error "Could not support development".  Xcode says that I'm up-to-date on the latest SDK.  How can I fix this?  I'm using Xcode 4.3.2 (4E2002).

Comment: have you tried this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652590/iphone-could-not-support-development

Answer (score 0):

Go to your organizer and make sure you have a green dot next to the device you are using. If not click Use For Development.

Comment: See yellow dot, not green.  Don't see any option for Use For Development.

Comment: What worked for me is removing from Organizer and Re-adding - @Nicholas

Comment: If you are seeing yellow dot in xCode organizer, so you need to update your xCode. I also faced this problem and updating xCode solve my problem.