# Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version - after upgrade to iOS 5.1.1 and Xcode 4.3.3

Tags: ios

Well, I was all set and ok when running xcode 4.2 and iOS 5.0, but after I upgraded the iPhone to 5.1.1 (9B206) and Xcode to 4.3.3 (4E3002), it is not being able to run the apps I am developing on my iPhone. In the Organizer it says:

**Software Version: 5.1.1 (9B206)
        Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version**

1) I checked the provisioning profiles, and they are ok, I reinstalled the whole certificates and provisioning profiles again, I got a green light next to my iPhone entry.

2) I checked for new updates, but the software are already updated

3) I saw the 5.1.1 sdk on the my hard drive under Xcode installation folder

/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/5.1.1 (9B206)

I searched the web and found a post on Apple support website telling the message "Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version" is not an error message, but a notification, and that I could still continue to work on my device, but after I tried to run the app I am developing on my iPhone, Xcode says :

**Xcode cannot run using the selected device.
No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version of iOS to run your application or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.**

So up to now I don't know that to do anymore, and I need help.

In my mind what I see is iOS SDK 5.1.1 installed on the iPhone and Xcode with iOS SDK 5.1.1 installed on my macbook pro Lion 10.7.4, and I cannot understand what is missing, or what I have to do to solve this situation, and start to run my apps on my iPhone with 5.1.1 + xcode 4.3.3.

iPhone 4S - Version 5.1.1 (9B206)
Model MD234BZ

XCode 4.3.3 (4E3002)

Mac OS X Version 10.7.4

Thank you very much!

Henrique

Answer (score 0):

just remove your xcode image from your dock list. After that open the project now you set the Keep in dock. it will remain.. because you set older version in dock.

Comment: check following things, Xcode--> preferences-->Documentation check installed core Libraries (or) install it like that Xcode--> preferences-->Components check required component installed or not

Comment: thanks. Actually this solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652590/iphone-could-not-support-development/4652629#4652629